# How to simplify Rails Active Record calculation based on condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Job has the following static method:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.super_job
    where('super_condition')
  end
  ...
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to rewrite the following?

```
jobs = Job.where(...)

if some_condition
  jobs = jobs.sum('my_field')
else
  jobs = jobs.super_job.sum('my_field')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :super_jobs, -> {where('super_condition')}
end

jobs = jobs.super_jobs unless some_condition
jobs.sum("my_field")
```

Answer (score 0):

I often do something like this for multiple criteria search:

```
def index 
  @jobs = find_jobs
end

.....

private


def find_jobs
  jobs = Job.where(...) #Global search, here I defined pagination if needed
  #Then I stack my queries with conditions
  jobs = jobs = jobs.sum('my_field') if/unless condition
  jobs = jobs.super_job.sum('my_field') if unless
  ...
end
```

It's barely the same as you do but it enough clear for me and my code is more "tidy".

Source: [railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised?view=asciicast)

Edit: as Vimsha says, scopes can help to clean the code too.

Hope it helps!